# Why did Romero cast a Black actor as the lead?

Tags: casting, night-of-the-living-dead

Back in the 1960s, it was not typically seen or accepted for a Black lead actor to be seen in mainstream American movies. So why did Romero cast Duane Jones as Ben in Night of the Living Dead?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this question. It was, of course, controversial at the time of release.

Answer (score 13):

George Romero said that Jones "simply gave the best audition."

[WikiPedia Notes about NOTLD Casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dead#Cast).

> Duane Jones was the best actor we met to play Ben. ... Consciously I resisted writing new dialogue ‘cause he happens to be black. We just shot the script. Perhaps 'Night of the Living Dead' is the first film to have a black man playing the lead role regardless of, rather than because of, his race.

[More quotes from Romero about Duane Jones](http://www.thewrap.com/night-living-dead-casting-cult-classic-20545/). From “Night of the Living Dead: Behind the Scenes of the Most Terrifying Zombie Movie Ever” (Citadel Press/Kensington, 2010).

But the movie's ending also can't help but serve as a biting social commentary as well.